# group_concat and join codeigniter giving fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

this is my query in model (in my sql this query is working fine but in code -igniter it gives me fatal error(Call to a member function result() on a non-object )

```
   $this->db->select('j.*, c.name as Cname, d.name as Dname, e.name as 
    Ename,GROUP_CONCAT(s.qualification SEPARATOR ",")  as  
    Qualification,GROUP_CONCAT(s.year SEPARATOR ",") as 
    Year,GROUP_CONCAT(s.institute SEPARATOR ",") as Institute' ); 
    $this->db->from('jobseekers j');
    $this->db->join('city c','c.id = j.location','left'); 
    $this->db->join('vertical e','e.id = j.vertical','left');
    $this->db->join('designation d','d.id = j.designation','left');
    $this->db->join('jobseekers_qul s','s.jobseekers_id = j.id','left');
    $this->db->group_by('j.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->result();
    return $row;
```

Comment: probably the $query returned false? Did you check? You don't seem to be checking for errors. Find out what it's complaining about. Quite possibly your query is _not_ in fact the same as the one you run in mysql

Comment: without group_concat working fine when i add group_concat it gives fatal error

Comment: yes but that's not the underlying error. That's just a PHP error saying you tried to use $query like an object when it's not. That has happened because your query failed. The query failed for some reason, and there will be a mysql error message you can retrieve which will show you what it is. I don't know your DB library but it will have documentation which shows you how to retrieve the underlying error. Find that error and post it here so that we can see exactly what the problem is. It's useful to know it happens with the group_concat, but the detailed error message would help a lot.

Comment: in the config/database.php file you've your db settings array - take a look @the key `db_debug`  and set it to `true`; after that you should see a formatted output of your DB error

Comment: it is true only , i am not able to find db error .

Comment: I think, comma is default separator in GROUP_CONCAT. So why you gave SEPARATOR?

Comment: Please post your table structure so can find you problem.

Comment: @kishor10d yup comma is default separator ,i just checked and now i am checking removing comma hope it will work

Comment: @kishor10d issue was comma only , thank you so much